# How to add literal text to the Unix 'cat' command

Tags: bash, cat

I'm trying to [cat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) some files together, while at the same time adding some text between files. I'm a Unix newbie and I don't have the hang of the syntax.

Here's my failed attempt:

```
cat echo "# Final version (reflecting my edits)\n\n" final.md echo "\n\n# The changes I made\n\n" edit.md echo "\n\n#Your original version\n\n" original.md > combined.md
```

How do I fix this? Should I be using pipes or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you, it should be something like:

```
echo "# Final version (reflecting my edits)\n\n" >> combined.md
cat final.md >> combined.md
echo "\n\n# The changes I made\n\n" >> combined.md
cat edit.md >> combined.md
```

And so on.

Answer (score 9):

A process substitution seems to work:

```
$ cat <(echo 'FOO') foo.txt <(echo 'BAR') bar.txt
FOO
foo
BAR
bar
```

You can also use command substitution inside a here-document.

```
$ cat <<EOF
FOO
$(< foo.txt)
BAR
$(< bar.txt)
EOF
```

Comment: You can embed command substitutions in the here-doc if you don't single-quote FOO.

Comment: @chepner Good to know, but how would I use it here?

Comment: I've edited your question rather heavily; I don't think you can combine here-strings with other file arguments to `cat` (in my testing, the here-strings are ignored).

Comment: @chepner Ah, I see now, thanks. Never really used here-strings like that.

Comment: @chepner Shouldn't there be 2 `<`'s then? `cat <<EOF...`

Answer (score 7):

Use a command group to merge the output into one stream:

```
{
   echo -e "# Final version (reflecting my edits)\n\n"
   cat final.md 
   echo -e "\n\n# The changes I made\n\n"
   cat edit.md 
   echo -e "\n\n#Your original version\n\n"
   cat original.md
} > combined.md
```

There are tricks you can play with process substitution and command substitution (see Lev Levitsky's answer) to do it all with one command (instead of the separate `cat` processes used here), but this should be efficient enough with so few files.

Comment: great option to avoiding having to repeatedly specify the same output file